# Is it safe to put the reCaptcha private key in the contact-us.php page?

Tags: php, html, recaptcha, contact-form

I'm new to web development and I would like to know if it's safe to put the reCaptcha private key in the contact-us.php page where I use 
`action="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]);?>"` to submit the form to the same page because of IE issues on submitting the form to other php page as sentmail.php or thankyou.php page where I could hide the reCaptcha private key?

Here is my code. If someone could help me understand where is the problem or how should I divide the code in 2 pages: contact.php and sendmail.php I will really appreciated.

```
    <?php 
    //set validation error flag as false
    $error = false;
    //check if form is submitted
    if (isset($_POST['submit']))
    {

        //Sanitize incoming data and store in variable
        $name = trim(stripslashes(htmlspecialchars($_POST['InputName'])));          
        $fromemail = trim(stripslashes(htmlspecialchars($_POST['InputEmail'])));
        $subject = trim(stripslashes(htmlspecialchars($_POST['InputSubject'])));        
        $message = trim(stripslashes(htmlspecialchars($_POST['InputMessage'])));


        //Validate data and return success or error message
        if (!preg_match("/^[a-zA-Z ]+$/",$name))
        {
            $error = true;
            $name_error = "Please Enter Valid Name";
        }

        if(!filter_var($fromemail,FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL))
        {
            $error = true;
            $fromemail_error = "Please Enter Valid Email Address";
        }
        if(empty($subject))
        {
            $error = true;
            $subject_error = "Please Enter Your Subject";
        }
        if(empty($message))
        {
            $error = true;
            $message_error = "Please Enter Your Message";
        }

        // grab recaptcha library
        require_once "recaptchalib.php";

        // your secret key
        $privatekey = "----------secret key-----------";

        //check reCaptcha
        if ($_POST["g-recaptcha-response"]) {
        $response_json = file_get_contents("https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/siteverify?secret=".urlencode($privatekey)."&response=".urlencode($_POST["g-recaptcha-response"]));
            $response = json_decode($response_json, true);
        }

        // if submitted check response
        if ($_POST["g-recaptcha-response"]) {
            $response = $reCaptcha->verifyResponse(
                $_SERVER["REMOTE_ADDR"],
                $_POST["g-recaptcha-response"]
            );
        }

        // empty response
        $response = null;

        // check secret key
        $reCaptcha = new ReCaptcha($privatekey);

        if (!$error)
        {
            // If there are no errors, send the email
            $toemail = "email@domain.com";
            $subject = "Message from Contact Form: " . $subject;
            $body = "Message from Contact Form: \n\n Name: $name \n From: $fromemail \n Subject: $subject\n Message: \n $message";
            $headers = "From: $fromemail\n";
            $headers .= "Reply-To: $fromemail";

            if (mail ($toemail, $subject, $body, $headers))
                $alertmsg  = '<div class="alert alert-success text-center">Thank you for contacting us. We will be in touch with you very soon.</div>';
            else
                $alertmsg = '<div class="alert alert-danger text-center">Sorry there was an error sending your message. Please try again later.</div>';
        }
    }
?>

<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Company | Contact us </title>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <!--[if IE]><script src="http://html5shiv.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/html5.js"></script><![endif]-->
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=EmulateIE9">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <!-- Bootstrap -->
        <link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
        <!-- jQuery (necessary for Bootstrap's JavaScript plugins) -->
        <script src="js/jquery.min.js"></script>
         <!-- Custom CSS files -->
        <link href="css/style.css" rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' />
        <!----webfonts--->

        <!-- Recaptcha -->
         <script type="text/javascript">
          var onloadCallback = function() {
            grecaptcha.render('html_element', {
              'sitekey' : '----sitekey------'
            });
          };
        </script>

    </head>

    <body>
    <!-- container -->
    <div class="container">
    <!-- header -->
         <header class="row">
            <!-- logo -->
            <div class="logo">
                <a href="index.html"><img src="images/logo.png" title="Logo" alt="Logo" width="300" height="125" /></a>
            </div><!--- End logo -->    
        </header>

        <!-- navbar -->
        <div class="row">
            <nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top" role="navigation">
                <div class="container-fluid">
                <!-- Toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
                    <div class="navbar-header">
                        <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapse" aria-expanded="false">
                            <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                        </button>
                    </div><!-- /.navbar-header -->  
                <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
                    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="collapse">
                        <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                            <li><a href="index.html">Home </a></li>
                            <li><a href="about.html">About us</a></li>
                            <li class="dropdown">
                                <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Services <span class="caret"></span></a>
                                <ul class="dropdown-menu">  
                                    <li><a href="services1.html">Services1</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="services2.html">Services2</a></li>
                                </ul>
                            </li>
                                        <li><a href="application.html">application</a></li>
                                    <li class="active"><a href="contact.html">Contact us <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a></li>
                                <form class="navbar-form navbar-left" role="search">
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                      <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Search">
                                    </div>
                                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Submit</button>
                                </form>
                         </ul>
                     </div><!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
                </div><!-- /.container-fluid -->
            </nav>
        </div><!-- navbar -->

    </div><!-- End container -->

                <!----MAP ---->
        <div class="welcome-note">
            <div class="container">
                    <div class="map">
                        <iframe src="link"></iframe>
                    </div>
            </div>
        </div><!---- MAP ---->
        <br/>

<!-- Contact with Map - START -->
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="contact-left col-md-4">
                <div class="panel panel-default text-center">
                    <div class="panel-body text-center">

                    <address>  

                    </address>
                    </div>
                </div>

        </div>

<!---- contact us form----->

    <div class="col-md-7">
        <div class="well well-md">
            <div><span><h2>Contact us</h2></span> 

            </div><br/>
            <form role="form" action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>" method="POST" id="contactForm"  enctype="multipart/form-data" data-toggle="validator" data-disable="false">

                <?php if (isset($alertmsg)) { echo $alertmsg; } ?>

                <fieldset>

                             <div class="form-group">
                            <div class="col-xs-10 col-md-offset-1">
                            <span class="text-danger"><?php if (isset($name_error)) echo $name_error; ?></span><br/>
                                <label for="InputName">Name *</label>
                                 <input type="text" class="form-control" name="InputName" id="InputName" placeholder="First & Last Name: Jane Doe" autocomplete="on" autofocus required value="<?php if($error) echo $name; ?>" />

                            </div>  
                            </div>  
                            <div class="form-group">
                            <div class="col-xs-10 col-md-offset-1">
                            <span class="text-danger"><?php if (isset($fromemail_error)) echo $fromemail_error; ?></span> <br/>
                                <label for="InputEmail">Email *</label>
                                 <input type="email" class="form-control" name="InputEmail" id="InputEmail" placeholder="Email: example@domain.com" autocomplete="on" required value="<?php if($error) echo $fromemail; ?>" />

                            </div>  
                            </div>                              
                            <div class="form-group">
                            <div class="col-xs-10 col-md-offset-1">
                            <span class="text-danger"><?php if (isset($subject_error)) echo $subject_error; ?></span> <br/>
                                <label for="InputSubject">Subject *</label>
                                <input type="text" class="form-control" name="InputSubject" id="InputSubject" placeholder="Subject" autocomplete="on" required value="<?php if($error) echo $subject; ?>" />

                            </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group">
                            <div class="col-xs-10 col-md-offset-1">
                            <span class="text-danger"><?php if (isset($message_error)) echo $message_error; ?></span><br/>
                                <label for="InputMessage">Message *</label> 
                                <textarea class="form-control" rows="5" name="InputMessage"  id="InputMessage"  placeholder="Enter your massage for us here. We will get back to you within 2 business days." autocomplete="off" required><?php if($error) echo $message; ?></textarea>

                            </div>
                            </div>

                            <div class="form-group">
                            <div class="col-xs-10 col-md-offset-1">
                            <br/>
                            <div class="g-recaptcha" data-sitekey="sitekey"></div>
                                 <script type="text/javascript">
                                      var onloadCallback = function() {
                                        alert("grecaptcha is ready!");
                                      };
                                    </script>
                            </div>
                            </div>

                            <!--<div class="form-group">
                                <div class="col-xs-10 col-md-offset-1">
                                <!-- input element hidden as dummy code for IE to can submit the form -->
                                <!--<input type="hidden" name="submit" id="submit" class="btn btn-primary" value="Send" />
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group">
                            <div class="col-xs-10 col-md-offset-1">
                                <button type="submit" id="submit" name="submit" class="btn btn-primary" value="Send">Send message <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-send"></span></button>
                                </div>
                            </div>-->

                </fieldset>
                <div class="col-md-4 col-md-offset-1">
                    <input type="submit" id="submit" name="submit" class="btn btn-primary" value="Send message" >
                </div>
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>

    </div>
    <div class="clearfix"> </div>
</div>

<!-- End contact -->


                <!-- javascript -->
                <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"></script>
                <script src="js/jquery.min.js"></script>
                <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
                <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
                <!-- Recaptcha -->
                <script src="https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js"></script>
    </body>

</html>
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking. See the [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) page for help clarifying this question.

Comment: it's in php code, which under normal circumstances would NEVER be visible to the end user, so... why not?

Comment: Thank you @Charlotte Not only I'm new to web development bur even my English is not the best. I would like to be safe with the reCaptcha private key. Should I put it in this page or should I create a new page in the includes folder outside of the public folder? If I have to create a new page for submitting the form I'm having issues with IE that doesn't happen anything when I click the submit button for this I created the form to submit to the same page. I would like to know if it's safe as single page or someone can help me figure out how to make the form work on IE to submit to another page.

Comment: @Mark I was thinking just like you do that the PHP never shows up in the html page when the users surf the page, but I'm not sure 100% so I'm asking help to the geeks. Thanks

Comment: As long as you don't print the private key (e.g. `echo $privatekey`), you can just put it into the php code and won't be visible to the end user, only to PHP.

Comment: @Charlotte Thanks. I'm a little bit paranoid with the security.

Comment: I'm still having issues when submitting this form. Can someone help me please??????? I would like to validate the form and reCaptcha and be able to submit or get errors in case validation requirements are not met. Thank you.